# How do I make a unified patch with diff?

Tags: patch, diff

I have two directories `src` and `src-with-fixes`. I want to make a unified patch, so people can download the `src` dir and the patch file and run `patch -p1 < patch.diff` and get the fixes in the src dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run:

```
diff -ruN src src-with-fixes > patch.diff
```

Where:

- `-r` means "recursive"
- `-u` means "produce a unified format diff"
- `-N` means "treat absent files as empty"

Comment: Incidentally, using `git` (or other VCS) makes this process a little more manageable. Definitely worth looking into if you have not worked with a version control system before.

Comment: I know of Git and I use it, but for this I don't want to use Git